# Match last occurence of 4 digits htaccess rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm wondering what sort of regex I could use to match the last occurence of a set of 4 digits in my url.

My url is being formatted like this

```
/ARTIST/ALBUM-4 DIGITS-EXTRA STUFF
```

In the url, "4 DIGITS" will be the last possible occurence of 4 digits together. The thing is the ALBUM may contain sets of 4 digits, so it needs to match the last occurrence in the url.

Basically I need my rewrite rule to act as follows

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-(.* MATCH LAST OCCURENCE OF 4 DIGITS)-(.*)?$ album.php?artist=$1&album=$2&releaseyear=$3&EXTRA=$4
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)-(\d{4})(?:-(.*))?$ album.php?artist=$1&album=$2&releaseyear=$3&EXTRA=$4
```

**[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/kQ9vY2/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)-(\d{4})-(\D*)$ album.php?artist=$1&album=$2&releaseyear=$3&EXTRA=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```